# How to download a .vcf file correctly

Tags: php, download, vcf-vcard

I'd like to know, how can I realise a Vcard download.
That's my current code:

```
$path = "../../media/resources/";  
$file = "someName.vcf";  

header('Content-Type: text/x-vCard');  
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename= "'.$file.'"');  
header('Content-Length: '.filesize($path.$file));  
header('Connection: close');  

readfile($path.$file);
```

Unfortunately, it does only give out the content from the .vcf file.
How can I give this vcard to the user as a download?

Comment: Are you sure the file defined by path `$path.$file` exists? Turn on `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 'on');` and repeat ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have `header('Connection: close');` which I would imagine closes the connection before the contents of the file are read. I've removed the line.

I'm not sure about case sensitivity in content-type so I changed it to x-vcard and I changed the content-disposition to inline (a known fix for download issues with IE). Try this:

```
$path = "../../media/resources/";  
$file = "Toni_Junas.vcf";  

header('Content-Type: text/x-vcard');  
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename= "'.$file.'"');  
header('Content-Length: '.filesize($path.$file));  

readfile($path.$file);
```

Also, make sure the directory "resources" is readable (chmod 755 on the directory) and that the file exists...

Comment: text/x-vcard is now deprecated in favour of  text/vcard   (https://tools.ietf.org/id/draft-ietf-vcarddav-vcardrev-02.html)

Answer (score 0):

put `exit()`

```
readfile($path.$file);
exit();
```

Comment: If the code specified above is the entire file (and it's best to assume it is), then exit would not be required

Comment: Why's this `exit()` for ? It's for the `flush()` behavior ?