# Force open vcard by php application

Tags: php, http, vcf-vcard

I have an application that generates vcards for instant share contacts, but i want these vcards to be opened by android/ios instead of downloaded.

These are the headers I'm passing:

```
$headers = [
    'Content-Type' => 'text/x-vcard',
    'filename' => $user->username . '.vcf',
    'Content-Disposition' => 'inline'
];
```

How can I force open the .vcf files?

Comment: Other vcards, the ones you don't create open and behave the way you do want them to? Just not yours? https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6350

Comment: I've never used any other application that generates vCards. I'll have to find one to test.

Comment: Update: I looked for some applications that generate vcard and none of them "force open" vcard

Comment: [How to download a .vcf file correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4461968/how-to-download-a-vcf-file-correctly)